# Displaying files under added directory through a merge in svn log

Tags: bash, svn

When using "svn log -v" directories that were added through a merge from a different branch show a merge reference, and all files contained within are omitted. Is there an easy way to display those files other than running the log command for the reference revision in the source branch?

IE:

```
$ svn commit -m "Added example dir"
Adding         dir
Adding         dir/a
Adding         dir/b
Transmitting file data ..done
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 16.

$ svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 16.

$ svn log -v -l 1 .
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r16 | U3FS | 2018-01-08 17:21:22 -0600 (Mon, 08 Jan 2018) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /lab/branches/source/dir
   A /lab/branches/source/dir/a
   A /lab/branches/source/dir/b

Added example dir

$ svn merge -c 16 ../source/ .
--- Merging r16 into '.':
A    dir
A    dir/a
A    dir/b
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r16 into '.':
 U   .

$ svn commit -m "Merged example dir"
Sending        .
Adding         dir
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 17.

$ svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 17.

$ svn log -v -l 1 .
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r17 | U3FS | 2018-01-08 17:23:41 -0600 (Mon, 08 Jan 2018) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /lab/branches/target
   A /lab/branches/target/dir (from /lab/branches/source/dir:16)

Merged example dir
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to be able to see the addition of 'a' and 'b' under 'dir/' for r17 in the 'target' branch. I'm thinking I'm gonna need some bash magic to combine the logs, but trying to avoid writing something much more complex than it needs to be. All ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly, `svn log -g` should do what I think you're attempting to do, which is to look at the merge history.

`svn log -vg` if you'd like it verbose (I prefer this one).

Comment: While the output isn't formatted in the way I had hoped, it does provide all the information I need. Thanks!